# video readyState always HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA after seek

Tags: javascript, html5-video

Hy,

I am trying to implement a synchronous playback of two videos with HTML5.
So when seeking one video should wait for the other to HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA before
starting to play both videos.

After `currentTime = seekPosition;` I imediately pause both videos and
check for readyState.
The readySates of both videos always are HAVE_ENOUGH_Data, so I `.play()` both of them.

I would think, that after `.play()` both videos would immediately start but sometimes they
have to load for a couple of seconds before playing back.

I test this in Chrome so it seems to me that the readyState is not used after a seek operation? Thanks for any ideas.

**EDIT**

Found this Bugreport http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=73609.
So it seems that the whole readystate / canplaythroug thing is very poorly implemented in Chrome.
According to this post https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=627153 the guys over at Mozilla are implementing it more accurately.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if a html5 video is ready](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181865/checking-if-a-html5-video-is-ready)