# how to run js code when video is fully buffered/loaded

Tags: html, video, load, buffer

I have searched all over google for this and nothing does what it is supposed to 
It works perfect in IE ... You can see it in the logs that it works perferct ... But it wont work in chrome!!! 
Why is it doing so in chrome ? ... It loads 10sek from catche and then nothing ...

```
<div style=" width:100%; height:320px; margin-top:-95px; background-image:url('video-logo.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"> 
<div id="videoRain" class="videoWrapper" style="text-align:center; display: none;"> 
<video id="rainVideo" width="100%" height="400px" preload="auto"> 
  <source src="rain-video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
  Your browser does not support the video tag. 
</video> 
</div> 
</div> 
<script> 
setTimeout(function(){ 
var refreshId = window.setInterval(function(){ 
   myVid=document.getElementById('rainVideo'); 
   puhvitud = Math.round(myVid.buffered.end(0)); 
   if (puhvitud >= 14) { 
  setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('videoRain').style.display='block';},0); 
      setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('rainVideo').play();},0); 
      clearInterval(refreshId); 
      setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('videoRain').style.display='none';},15000); 
   } 
   console.log(puhvitud); 
}, 2000); 
},1000); 
</script>
```

Maybe someone has another way to do this ?
When the video is fully loaded ... this should be ran...

```
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('videoRain').style.display='block';},0); 
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('rainVideo').play();},0); 
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('videoRain').style.display='none';},15000);
```

---

EDIT:

Tried this:

```
    <script>

        function runVideoRain(){
            rainVideo.addEventListener("loadeddata", runRain, false);
        }
    function runRain()
    {
        setTimeout(function()                {document.getElementById('videoRain').style.display='block';},0);
        setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('rainVideo').play();},0);
        setTimeout(function()        {document.getElementById('videoRain').style.display='none';},15000);
    }, false);
    </script>
```

Does not work !!

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , 
Uncaught ReferenceError: runVideoRain is not defined
onloadeddata

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if a html5 video is ready](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181865/checking-if-a-html5-video-is-ready)

Comment: Onloadeddata="myfunc()" - does not work !!! ... readyState === 4 - does not work! ... canplaythrough - does not work! ... these just load the video for a fiew seconds

Comment: just tried this ... oncanplaythrough ... it just starts the funcktion when the video tag is loaded and does not wait for the video to load!!

Comment: FYI (3 years after question) 'canplay' works on current Chrome. Javascript example:  `var video = document.getElementById('myvideo');` `video.oncanplay = function(){...};`  For example, I tested fading out an image that overlaid the video, while starting the video playing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the onloadeddata attribute.

> onloadeddata : Script to be run when media data is loaded

```
<video id="rainVideo" width="100%" height="400px" preload="auto" onloadeddata="runMyFunction();"> 
  <source src="rain-video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
  Your browser does not support the video tag. 
</video> 
<script>
    function runMyFunction(){
        alert('The video is loaded');
    }
</script>
```

It seems that onloadeddata attribute does not work on chrome. But attaching an event handler through addEventListener does the trick !

```
rainVideo.addEventListener("loadeddata", myRunFunction, false);
//with jQuery
$(rainVideo).on("loadeddata", myRunFunction);
```

Comment: if i use this ... what this does is that when your video data has loaded as much as fiew seconds or less(DOES NOT LOAD THE FULL VIDEO) ... and then runs the function() ... So this does not help ...

Comment: It seems that onloadeddata attribute does not work on chrome. But attaching an event handler through addEventListener does the trick ! I edited my answer. It works on my Chrome Browser, now. And it works with jQuery too.

Comment: how do i add the ... display='block'; ... play(); ... display='none'; ... to it?

Comment: without jQuery : document.getElementById('rainVideo').style.display="none"; document.getElementById('rainVideo').style.display="display";

Comment: What i ment was ... where do i put these ? ... if you mean that i should put these instead of the ... alert('The video is loaded'); ... then it will not work ... tried this

Comment: It works on my computer. (be carefull : document.getElementById('rainVideo').style.display="block";    I wrote display instead of block

Comment: Do you mean this works for You ? ... http://i.stack.imgur.com/UscXv.png ... try it yourself ... does this page work with your chrome ? ... http://rasim.ee/martin/hmm/index.html