# How can I correctly provide a mock webcam video to Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, video, ffmpeg, mocking, webcam

I'm trying to run end-to-end testing in Chrome for a product that requires a webcam feed halfway through to operate. From what I understand this means providing a fake webcam video to Chrome using the `--use-file-for-fake-video-capture="/path/to/video.y4m"` command line argument. It will then use that as a webcam video.

However, no matter what y4m file I provide, I get the following error from Chrome running under these conditions:

```
DOMException: Could not start video source
{
  code: 0,
  message: "Could not start video source",
  name: "NotReadableError"
}
```

Notably **I can provide an audio file just fine** using `--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture` and Chrome will work with it well. The video has been my sticking point.

This error comes out of the following straightforward mediaDevices request:

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
  .then(data => {
    // do stuff
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // oh no!
  });
```

(This always hits the “oh no!” branch when a video file is provided.)

## What I've tried so far

I've been running Chrome with the following command line arguments (newlines added for readability), and I'm using a Mac hence the `open` command:

```sh
open -a "Google Chrome" --args
  --disable-gpu
  --use-fake-device-for-media-stream
  --use-file-for-fake-video-capture="~/Documents/mock/webcam.y4m"
  --use-file-for-fake-audio-capture="~/Documents/mock/microphone.wav"
```

`webcam.y4m` and `microphone.wav` were generated from a video file I recorded.

I first recorded a twenty-second mp4 video using my browser's MediaRecorder, downloaded the result, and converted it using the following command line commands:

```sh
ffmpeg -y -i original.mp4 -f wav -vn microphone.wav
ffmpeg -y -i original.mp4 webcam.y4m
```

When this didn't work, I tried the same using a twenty-second movie file I recorded in Quicktime:

```sh
ffmpeg -y -i original.mov -f wav -vn microphone.wav
ffmpeg -y -i original.mov webcam.y4m
```

When *that also* failed, I went straight to [the Chromium file that explains fake video capture](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/media/capture/video/file_video_capture_device.h?l=31), went to [the example y4m file list](https://media.xiph.org/video/derf/) it provided, and downloaded the grandma file and provided that as a command line argument to Chrome instead:

```sh
open -a "Google Chrome" --args
  --disable-gpu
  --use-fake-device-for-media-stream
  --use-file-for-fake-video-capture="~/Documents/mock/grandma_qcif.y4m"
  --use-file-for-fake-audio-capture="~/Documents/mock/microphone.wav"
```

Chrome provides me with the *exact* same error in *all* of these situations.

The only time Chrome doesn't error out with that mediaDevices request is when I omit the video completely:

```sh
open -a "Google Chrome" --args
  --disable-gpu
  --use-fake-device-for-media-stream
  --use-file-for-fake-audio-capture="~/Documents/mock/microphone.wav"
```

## Accounting for C420mpeg2

[TestRTC](https://testrtc.com/y4m-video-chrome/) suggests Chrome will “crash” if I give it a `C420mpeg2` file, and recommends that simply replacing the metadata fixes the issue. Indeed the video file I generate from ffmpeg gives me the following header:

```sh
YUV4MPEG2 W1280 H720 F30:1 Ip A1:1 C420mpeg2 XYSCSS=420MPEG2
```

Chrome doesn't actually crash when run with this file, I just get the error above. If I edit the video file to the following header though per TestRTC's recommendations I get the same situation:

```sh
YUV4MPEG2 W1280 H720 F30:1 Ip A1:1 C420 XYSCSS=420MPEG2
```

The video file still gives me the above error in these conditions.

## What can/should I do?

How should I be providing a video file to Chrome for this command line argument?

How should I be recording or creating the video file?

How should I convert it to y4m?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

After reading the link you provided I noticed that we can also provide an **mjpeg**.

Depending on what your test requirements - this may be sufficient for you. As a terminal command with ffmpeg installed:

```sh
ffmpeg -i oldfile.mp4 newfile.mjpeg
```

then I tested by running Google Chrome from the terminal using:

```sh
google-chrome --use-fake-device-for-media-stream --use-file-for-fake-video-capture=newfile.mjpeg
```

After navigating to [Tracking JS](https://trackingjs.com/examples/face_camera.html) I could see the video being played back.

I hope that works for you!

Comment: Precise solution for simulating a webcam for chrome without a loopback device. great work.

Comment: Hi, where do I write these lines ?

Comment: Also, if someone wants to generate a video from a single repeated image, you can do it as:
`ffmpeg -loop 1 -i inputImage.png -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 0.05 outputVideo.y4m`
(Chrome loops the video, so you don't need to worry about the duration.. I specified 0.05 seconds so that the created file is small)

Answer (score 9):

If someone ever needs to mock a video dynamically, this is what I've used (forked from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52464583/possible-to-get-puppeteer-audio-feed-and-or-input-audio-directly-to-puppeteer))

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
        const video = document.createElement("video");

        video.setAttribute('id', 'video-mock');
        video.setAttribute("src", 'https://woolyss.com/f/spring-vp9-vorbis.webm');
        video.setAttribute("crossorigin", "anonymous");
        video.setAttribute("controls", "");

        video.oncanplay = () => {
            const stream = video.captureStream();

            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = () => Promise.resolve(stream);
        };

        document.querySelector("body").appendChild(video);
    });
```

- the key is to return `Promise.resolve(stream)`
- `oncanplay` is better than `onplay` because it is triggered [after the video is playable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181865/checking-if-a-html5-video-is-ready)

This flags are still necessary:

```
'--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream',
'--use-fake-device-for-media-stream',
```

In the end, with this script different camera mocks are possible for every page - especially useful when using browserless!

Answer (score 7):

## Mocked/Fake Raw Video (2021)

Use y4m if you want raw frames without Chrome having to run a decoder:

```
ffmpeg -i original.avi -pix_fmt yuv420p video-for-chrome.y4m
```

Then, start Chrome:

```
chrome.exe --use-fake-device-for-media-stream --use-file-for-fake-video-capture=video-for-chrome.y4m
```

Note:  There is no longer any reason to have to modify your y4m file's header.  Chrome has since been fixed.

This method uses less CPU, but will take up a good deal of hard drive space for the raw video.  Keep your video file short.  Chrome will loop it.

Comment: this solution worked for me, I'm using playwright for opening the browser

Comment: this doesn't seem to work on windows, but works on mac. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: @No_name I'm using this on Windows.

Comment: on linux I had to specify the size in order for this to work I've used: `ffmpeg -i original.png  -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1280x720 video-for-chrome.y4m` and worked

Comment: @brad, thanks for your answer! Please note that it should be `--use-fa...` instead of `--user-fa...`. See [this link](https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/testing/) for other options

Comment: @No_name I can confirm this is NOT working on `Windows 10 Home Build 19043.1526` and `Chrome Version 98.0.4758.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)`. I am calling it like this `& "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream --use-file-for-fake-video-capture=test.y4m'`, but it's still using the real webcam everywhere (e.g.: https://webcamtests.com/).

Comment: @Fapaz Drop those quotes around your args.

Comment: @Brad Apologies, that was copied from one of my many tests. This still doesn't work: `& "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --use-fake-device-for-media-stream --use-file-for-fake-video-capture=test.y4m`. I also tried ditching the fake video capture, added the arguments in the Target of a shortcut, executed ffmpeg with different parameters, etc. Can't find much online either, so I'm wondering whether this Chrome flag has been compromised recently.

Comment: Progress! I went to chrome://version on my browser and noticed that none of the flags were present in `Command Line`. So I closed all Chrome instances (as instructed [here](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags/#windows)) and executed the shell command again. It works now... partially. If I provide just the `--use-fake-device-for-media-stream`, it fakes the stream with a default test video as expected. However, the webcam is not being detected anywhere if I provide a fake video capture (either y4m or mjpeg).

Comment: @Fapaz Yes, your webcam will no longer work if you're using a faked media stream.

Comment: @Brad Sorry I mean the fake video stream wasn't working at all. Eventually I figured out that I had to provide the absolute path to the fake video instead. As I couldn't edit your answer, I posted my own down below. I have upvoted yours anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

### How to mock webcam on Chrome for Windows

(Tested with `Windows 10 Home Build 19043.1526` and `Chrome Version 98.0.4758.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)`)

Install [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html), then run the following command in your shell to convert your mp4 to mpjeg:

```
./ffmpeg.exe -i originalVideo.mp4 output.mjpeg
```

**Alternatively**, you could also create a y4m video from a png image (thanks @LGenzelis):

```
./ffmpeg.exe -loop 1 -i myStaticImage.png -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 0.05 output.y4m
```

**Close all Chrome instances**, then run the following command in your shell:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --use-fake-device-for-media-stream --use-file-for-fake-video-capture="C:/absolute/path/to/output.mjpeg"
```

Then test it on a website like https://webcamtests.com/

### Troubleshooting

#### Chrome still showing stream from real camera

Make sure there are no other Chrome instances running before launching it with those arguments.

#### Camera not found

Make sure you're providing the **absolute** path to your video in `--use-file-for-fake-video-capture` (e.g.: `"C:/absolute/path/to/output.mjpeg"` instead of just `output.mjpeg`)

Comment: Using the absolute path fixed it for me. But I had to remove the `&` from the beginning of the command to launch Chrome - not sure what that was intended for.

Comment: @TimMB that's probably a typo or leftover while copying/pasting, it's been fixed, thanks.