# Web camera mocks not working with S3 pre-signed videos in Playwright

Tags: amazon-s3, mocking, webcam, playwright, capturestream

I have several **Playwright** tests that use a webcam to capture videos and photos. Now they work with stubs via `'--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream','--use-fake-device-for-media-stream'`

I would really like to dynamically use video mocks for happy e2e tests.

After studying the problem a little, I managed to mock `public .mp4` streams into the video element used for the webcam feed.

In my CI/CD pipeline, all test data (including camera videos) are stored as `pre-signed AWS S3 links` like `https://my-e2e.s3.amazonaws.com/resources/my-face.webm?AWSAccessKeyId=ABC123FAKE&Signature=ABC123FAKED&Expires=1660724194`

But such videos don't work at all with the suggested CaptureStream workaround.

You can check the working snippet in [jsfiddle playground](https://jsfiddle.net/f4sbu0v6/1/)

I have a bad feeling it might be restricted by:

> Attempting to use captureStream() with a media element that implements content protection via Encrypted Media Extensions will throw an exception.

Or I am missing something about streaming videos from AWS...

**UPD Oct 2022:** Adding * as allowed origin to CORS settings of S3 bucket resolved my issue.

**References:**

- [How to mock a video dynamically using JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64034376/9337206)
- [How captureStream works with video elements](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/capture-stream/)

Comment: You haven't encrypted the stream, so that warning shouldn't apply.  What does the network tab of your browser's dev tools show?  It's likely you have a cross-site error, and you'll need to [enable CORS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-configure-cors/) for the bucket.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed my s3 bucket didn't have any CORS configuration. I added * as the allowed origin and it works now!